# ArrayList from user model returns null

Tags: java, android, arraylist, nullpointerexception

So in the app I'm creating I have a user class defined as the following

```
public class User implements Serializable{

private int id;
private String username;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String email;
private String password;
private String picture;
private ArrayList<String> tags;
private double rating;
private Category favorite;
private boolean star;
private Location homeLocation;


public User(int id, String username, String firstName,String lastName,String picture, ArrayList<String> tags,double rating, Category favorite, boolean star,Location homeLocation,String email,String password) {
    this.id = id;
    this.username = username;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.picture = picture;
    this.tags = tags;
    this.rating = rating;
    this.favorite = favorite;
    this.star = star;
    this.homeLocation = homeLocation;
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;

}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public String getLastName(){ return lastName;}

public String getPicture(){ return picture;}

public ArrayList<String> getTags() {
    return tags;
}

public double getRating(){ return rating;}

public Category getFavorite(){ return favorite;}

public Boolean getStar(){ return star;}

public Location getHomeLocation(){return homeLocation;}

public String getEmail(){return email;}

public String getPassword(){return password;}

public void setId(int id){

    this.id = id;

}
```

Now, when I create a User object I pass an `ArrayList<String>` tags which, when logged, shows just as intended.

```
List<String> listTags = Arrays.asList(DummyTags.tagsNewUser);
ArrayList<String> tags = new ArrayList<>();

tags.addAll(listTags);

Log.d("Tags",tags.toString());

user = new User(0,userName,firstName,lastName,picturePlaceHolder,tags,4,category,true,loc,email,password);
```

However, when I use this user object in, say a profile page, and retrieve the users tags through the getter in the class it always returns null.

```
user = (User) getArguments().getSerializable("User");

tags = user.getTags();
```

Doing this always has tags be null, no matter what `ArrayList` I pass when creating the user object.

I also get a warning in android studio saying that invoking `user.getTags()` may produce a npe. Every other part of the user model works just fine. I have tried to solve this for a while now and have not been able to find anything relating to my problem so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: From where are you passing data and how ??

Comment: When you are trying to get the user from arguments, you probably would have set it somewhere and passed it to this activity. How are you setting that User value into the bundle

Comment: In this case, because the database I'm retrieving user data from doesnt include the tag information yet, I'm just trying to pass some constant list to see how the tags look on the profile page. First time posting here so if I forgot to add anything relevant please tell me.

But basically when creating a new user it takes the dummy tags in a constants class and adds them to the user model. Later, in the profile fragment, I retrieve this user object. Every other variable, such as name, rating etc. works perfect - just the tags give me a npe

Comment: So, getting the user object from the argument works well - it just returns null for the tags although I passed a valid arraylist. The entire structure is quite complex and I dont want to paste endless amount of related code

Comment: Your getting nullpointerexception, because your not passing any objects to your arraylist, without see the code its a guessing game.

Comment: Yeah, as I said - I am taking the array list from a class called "DummyTags" which acts as a replacement for the database tag implementation. I was logging the tags before passing it to the user object, and it correctly shows up. Later, when trying to retrieve it - it returns null although all other variables work fine. I understand that it might not be something I could just put on stackoverflow and expect a solution. So thanks for your help, I guess I'll post and update once I solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
    bundle.putStringArrayList("tags",tags);
    bundle.putSerializable("User",user);
```

and then retrieve as:

```
tags = getArguments().getStringArrayList("tags");
```

The reason that your solution does not work is that ArrayList is not implementing Serializable interface

Comment: That sounds like it could be the problem! Thank you for the tip, will try it out later and mark as correct if it ends up working (I think it will)!